# Quick Look shows incorrect dates for Excel file

Tags: finder, ms-office, quicklook

When I press space to preview an Excel file in Quick Look, the dates are incorrect

[image: Quick Look]

The dates are correct when the same file is opened in Excel.

[image: Excel]

Is it possible to fix this by adjusting the Excel file?

Comment: Not sure the reason for this. How are the cells in Excel formatted, date or otherwise? What happens when you try different formats for these cells, again date or otherwise?

Comment: `=CELL("format", B2)` returns `G` (general), `=CELL("type", B2)` returns `v`, `=TYPE(B2)` returns 1. Here's the documentation for the [CELL](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/cell-function-51bd39a5-f338-4dbe-a33f-955d67c2b2cf) and [TYPE](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/type-function-45b4e688-4bc3-48b3-a105-ffa892995899) functions

Comment: Not sure again but the issue could be your macOS **System Preferences > Language&Region > Advanced > Dates** settings if they are non-US. I have seen some native macOS apps processing dates unexpectedly when those settings are set to non-US. Maybe you could also try formatting those cells differently and see what Quick Look does in order to understand the issue a bit better.